# Kubernetes - Default Network Policy when creating a new namespace

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I'm running canal CNI on a Kubernetes cluster and need to prevent inter-namespace communication. So, every time a new namespace is created, I need to have a default deny network policy created as well.

I can do this from outside Kubernetes. i.e. cron a bash script or ansible playbook, that gets all the namespaces in my cluster and applies this default deny for every namespace that exists. But that doesn't feel very clean.

Rancher can create policies that prevent inter-project communication, but that doesn't quite fulfill my use-case. If namespace-A and namespace-B fall within the same project, pods within these namespaces will be able to communicate with one another.

Are there any plugins, add-ons, CRDs, or mutating webhooks available that can assist with this? I've done a few searches but came up with nothing concrete.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Kubernetes doesn't offer to do this.

One way to work around this could be to write your own operator - using the operator-sdk makes it pretty easy. I used to write one watching for Namespaces resources / no CRD (on a private Git I can no longer access). I see others introducing a CRD [1], which could allow for more flexibility.

Using some Admission Controller could do as well [2].

Meanwhile, OKD / OpenShift offers some "default Project template", that you could edit adding your own objects, changing the default rolebindings/permissions granted to the user requesting that project to be created.

Similar topics @SO:

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967984/automatically-creating-resources-objects-with-creation-of-namespace-in-kubernete

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62136128/automatically-create-kubernetes-resources-after-namespace-creation/62604439#62604439